# In expressjs how would I limit the number of users who can make a request at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My code is just a regular app:

```
app
  .use(sassMiddleware({
      src: __dirname + '/sass',
      dest: __dirname + '/',
      // This line controls sass log output
      debug: false,
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
  }))

  // More libraries
  ...

  .get('/', auth.protected, function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
  })

.post('/dostuff', auth.protected, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.redirect('back')

    child = require('child_process').spawn(
        './script.rb',
        ['arguments'],
        { stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe'] }
    );
    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    child.stderr.pipe(process.stdout);
  })
```

My original goal is to limit the number of spawns that /dostuff can spawn to a single instance. I was thinking that there might be a simple way to limit the number of users on the entire app, but can't seem to find any.

I was trying to look for some session limiting mechanism but can't find one either, only various rate limiters but I don't think that's what I want.

Since the app is running in docker I limit the number of tcp connections on the port using iptalbes but this has proven to be less then ideal since the app retains some connections in `established` state which prevents efficient hand off from one user to another.

So... any programmatic way of doing this?

***UPDATE***

The app is not an api server. `/dostuff` is actually triggered by the user from a webpage. That's why simple rate limiting is not the best option. Also the times of execution for the ruby script are variable.

***ANSWER***

Based on the answer below from @jfriend00, by fixing a couple of logical errors I came up with:

```
  .post('/dostuff*', auth.protected, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)

    if (spawnCntr >= spawnLimit)  {
        res.status(502).send('Server is temporarily busy');
        console.log("You already have process running. Please either abort the current run or wait until it completes".red)
        return;
    }

    let childClosed = false
    function done () {
        if (!childClosed) {
          --spawnCntr;
          childClosed = true;
        }
    }

    ++spawnCntr;

    child = require('child_process').spawn(
        blahblah
    );

    child.on('close', done);
    child.on('error', done);
    child.on('exit', done);

    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    child.stderr.pipe(process.stdout);

    res.redirect('back');
  })
```

I am still going to accept his answer although incomplete it helped a lot.

Comment: Is my answer helpful or do you need anything else?

Comment: @DamienGold updated my answer to explain why I think rate limiting would be clunky in this situation.

Comment: I updated my answer. The second option should work for you. If it does, mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a simple counter of how many `spawn()` operations are in process at the same time and if a new request comes in and you are currently over that limit, you can just return a 502 error (server temporarily busy).

```
let spawnCntr = 0;
const spawnLimit = 1;

app.post('/dostuff', auth.protected, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)

    if (spawnCntr > spawnLimit) }
        return res.status(502).send("Server temporarily busy");
    }

    let childClosed = false;
    function done() {
        // make sure we count it closing only once
        if (!childClosed) {
            --spawnCntr;
            childClosed = true;
        }
    }
    ++spawnCntr;
    let child = require('child_process').spawn(
        './script.rb',
        ['arguments'],
        { stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe'] }
    );
    // capture all the ways we could know it's done
    child.on('close', done);
    child.on('error', done);
    child.on('exit', done);

    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    child.stderr.pipe(process.stdout);

    res.redirect('back');
  });
```

Note: The code in your question does not declare `child` as a local variable which looks like a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: The reason why I don't declare child as a function variable is because I need to be able to terminate it from another ```.get``` request.

Comment: @user3081519 - Then `spawnLimit` has to be `1` because if it's any other value, then you will overwrite the `child` variable when you spawn the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node package Express Rate Limit - https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit.

For an API-only server where the rate-limiter should be applied to all requests:

```
var RateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

app.enable('trust proxy'); // only if you're behind a reverse proxy (Heroku, Bluemix, AWS if you use an ELB, custom Nginx setup, etc) 

var limiter = new RateLimit({
  windowMs: 15*60*1000, // 15 minutes 
  max: 100, // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs 
  delayMs: 0 // disable delaying - full speed until the max limit is reached 
});

//  apply to all requests 
app.use(limiter);
```

For a "regular" web server (e.g. anything that uses express.static()), where the rate-limiter should only apply to certain requests:

```
var RateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

app.enable('trust proxy'); // only if you're behind a reverse proxy (Heroku, Bluemix, AWS if you use an ELB, custom Nginx setup, etc) 

var apiLimiter = new RateLimit({
  windowMs: 15*60*1000, // 15 minutes 
  max: 100,
  delayMs: 0 // disabled 
});

// only apply to requests that begin with /api/ 
app.use('/api/', apiLimiter);
```

Comment: This does not seem like a rate limiting problem.  The spawned process runs for an indeterminate time so there is no way to use a timed rate limiter to manage only only one spawned process at a time without massively overstating the time limit such that you can't even do one request and when it finishes, do another.  This is simply not a rate limiting problem as even the OP has already said.